# custom authentication in restlet 1.0

Tags: restlet

I am using Restlet framework of 1.0 version. I am able to secure using Basic authentication with static username and password credentials.

But if I need to validate the user name and password with users available in ldap or db, how can i do that in 1.0? I couldn't see the custom authentication examples in Restlet framework 1.0 documentation.

Please help if possible with an example.

Note: I cannot upgrade to latest versions of restlet framework atleast now due to other dependencies.

Comment: I think you have to read sections 1 to 9 at this link: http://web.archive.org/web/20060106085240/http://www.restlet.org:80/tutorial . There in the section 9, you will find a function named `authorize(userId,password)`. Change the function-body according to your needs.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, thanks for your reply. But I dont see that GuardChainlet class in my restlet jar. Is it of 1.0?

Comment: According to http://nixbit.com/software/restlet-1.0-beta-review/ GuardChainlet is in Restlet since Restlet-1.0-Beta-22.Try Downloading that jar or higher version from restlet.com or waybackmachine.org . If that is not an option, then download the relevant restlet source code, add the required class(es) to your code.

Comment: Hmm.. will try upgrade as the last option but if you can find examples or any reference for  customization of authentication and authorization using Guard will be more helpful. Documentation of that is incomplete here: https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/tutorials/1.0/guard-access. They mentioned it is customizable with Guard but not any details on how.

Comment: I got customizing the Guard methods based on your links. Thanks for your inputs.
For Eg:
Guard guard = new Guard(router.getContext(), ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, configuration.getString("Restlet tutorial"))
{
 
      protected boolean checkSecret(String identifier, char[] secret)
             {
    // customize according to our needs here
                return identifier.equals("scott") && new String(secret).equals("tiger");
             }
};

Comment: Convert your last comment as an answer to your own question, and select that as an accepted answer, so that this question gets marked as [solved].